# Como exibir uma mensagem em uma <div></div> limpa!

Tags: php, html

Como posso exibir uma mensagem em uma div que não tem nenhum conteudo ou tag.

```
Ex: <div class="mensagem"></div>
```

**$msg = "Olá, Mundo";**

queria exibir essa mensagem da variavel $msg na tag div, não quero simplesmente utilizar `<div class="mensagem">echo $msg;</div>`

preciso entender como isso funciona!

Comment: Não consegui entender, o que você quer é exibir a variável PHP `$msg` na `div`?

Comment: Não está muito claro o que está a tentar fazer. Sugiro que dê um exemplo mais perto do que precisa mesmo de fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que você quer é exibir a mensagem da variável PHP `$msg`, você pode fazer de duas maneiras bem simples:

**Curta:**

```
<div class="mensagem"><?= $msg ?></div>
```

**Tradicional:**

```
<div class="mensagem"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
```

Também tem como fazer utilizando JavaScript/JQuery, porém não vejo por qual motivo iria fazer isso nesse exemplo:

```
<div class="mensagem"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('.mensagem').innerText = '<?= $msg ?>';
</script>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
    $('.mensagem').text('<?= $msg ?>');
</script>
```

Você poderia ver:

- [Diferença entre tags do php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/279723/como-exibir-uma-mensagem-em-uma-div-div-limpa)

Cursos em vídeo que podem te ajudar a começar:

- [Curso de PHP para iniciantes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7KzJ7e6EAc&list=PLHz_AreHm4dm4beCCCmW4xwpmLf6EHY9k)
- [Curso de POO PHP (Programação Orientada a Objetos)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlIL63MeyMY&list=PLHz_AreHm4dmGuLII3tsvryMMD7VgcT7x)
- [Curso de Lógica de Programação](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mei6uVttho&list=PLHz_AreHm4dmSj0MHol_aoNYCSGFqvfXV)
- [Curso de HTML5 Completo e GRÁTIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epDCjksKMok&list=PLHz_AreHm4dlAnJ_jJtV29RFxnPHDuk9o)

Tem outros cursos além desses no canal dele, esse canal é ótimo pra quem está começando.